# Kettle: Filling field with sequence without conflict

Tags: sequence, pentaho, kettle

I have a data stream with the following structure

```
user_id (integer)
user_name (string)
```

The `user_id` is anything between 100 and 65536. I want to add a `target_user_id` (integer) field according to the following logic:

- If `user_id` is in range 1000..9999, then let the `target_user_id` field be equal to the `user_id`
- If not, then fill `target_user_id` with something in range 1000..9999 without causing a conflict. Preferably the lowest possible.

The length of the stream is under 9000. The `user_id` field is unique in the original stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what Kettle environment you are using but a general procedure could be as follows:

1. Create a temporary database table (Maybe an in-memory database table)
2. Initialise it with records with user_id 1000..9999 and user_name=null (use TableOutput)
3. Open the input stream and process records with user_id 1000..9999 by updating the respective database record with the user_name. (use Update) Ignore all other records.
4. Close and reopen the input stream
5. Process each input stream record with user_id not in 1000..9999 by:

   - get the lowest unused user_id by executing a SQL query (DBLookup)

     ```
     SELECT MIN(user_id) FROM temporary_table WHERE user_name IS NULL;
     ```
   - Update this record with the current user_name (use Update)
6. Read each record in the temporary database table with a non null user_name (use TableInput) and write to output stream
7. Delete temporary database table

Hope this helps

Comment: This solves it, but has an overhead: subselect from every row. --- I have a "User Defined Java Class" based concept which would merge the ouput of a Sequence and the ordered data set. It would have a TreeSet (java class) for seen ids. --- I think this is not a very rare demand, so there should be a non-programmer solution for that. Maybe, I'm dreaming :-) The "TableOutput" hint is very valuable for me anyways.